# Elliptically symmetric random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, spheres

Let $X$ is elliptically symmetric distributed random vector. Then $X$ can be expressed in the form $$X =^d \mu + R A U$$
where $R$ is a nonnegative random variabel and $U$ is uniformly distributed random vector in unit sphere, $U$ and $R$ are mutually independent. Is it true that $R =^d ||X||$ ? Where $||X||$ denote euclidean norm of $X$. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What is $A$? What is $A$?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix such that $AA^T = \Sigma$

Comment: You may forget about the random variables, ellipses an the unit sphere. Your question is as follows. Let $u$ and $\mu$ be vectors and let $r$ be a positive number. Is then true that $\|\mu+rAu\|=r$? If $\mu=0$ then $\|rAu\|=r\|Au\|$. Is $\|Au\|=1?$

Comment: @zoli : I have found the answer in this [link](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dpaindav/stuff/Articles/Article48/elliptical.pdf). But, now I interest to know the probability density function from random vector uniformly distributed in n-sphere. In the simple example, let $Y = [y_1,y_2]$ is random vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y$ uniformly distributed in unit circle. I guess that $Y$ have p.d.f $f(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$. But I don't have idea to show $\int \int \frac{1}{2\pi} dy_1dy_2= 1$. Do you have suggestion for me ?